# Jest Vue: Is it possible to load dynamic imports for snapshot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a Vue component that dynamically loads it's child component. The problem is that Jest / Vue utils doesn't seem to be able to render it. Is there any way of doing this?

My component

```js
<template>
  <component :is="component" v-bind="props" />
</template>

<script>
const components = {
  dog: () => import('./dog.vue'),
  cat: () => import('./cat.vue')
}

export default {
  props: { type: String }

  computed: {
    component() {
      return components[this.type]
    }

    props() { ... }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my test

```js
...
it('renders correctly', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component, { ... })

  expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
})
...
```

And this is the resulting snapshot file

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`Markdown Token renders correctly 1`] = `<!---->`;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't load the dynamic component in the first loading cycle but you can update the props to ensure the component will import the lazy-loaded component before checking the snapshot.
In these examples, I am trying to reset the `type` property, so that the dynamic component will be imported soon after.

Vue utils example:

```
test('render dog component', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component, { ... });

  // Reset props if you have already passed it as `dog`
  await wrapper.setProps({ type: '' });
  // Now set it again.
  await wrapper.setProps({ type: 'dog' }); 

  expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Testing library example:

```
test('render dog component', async () => {
  const { html, updateProps } = render(Component, { ... });

  // Reset props if you have already passed it as `dog`
  await updateProps({ type: '' });
  // Now set it again.
  await updateProps({ type: 'dog' }); 

  expect(html()).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

### Update:

The best approach might be loading lazy-loaded components before checking the snapshots:

```
test('render dog component', async () => {
  const { html } = render(Component, { ... });

  await Promise.all([import('./dog.vue'), import('./cat.vue')]); 

  expect(html()).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

Comment: It took some fooling around, but it worked! Thanks a lot.